# How to keep the quality of uploaded image files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net MVC 5 application using C# language and one of the web pages lets users upload image files which have different dimensions in different aspect ratios.

An uploaded image file will be shown on another web page with fixed dimension :  w = 130px and height = 23px , and HTML img tag like `<img src="xyz..." style="width:130px; height:23px" />`

How can I write C# codes with a particular logic or algorithm to save uploaded image files on server with respect to those fixed dimensions (130px by 23px) and aspect ratio of 5.65, which is 130/23, when users' original image files are in different dimensions and aspect ratios? The quality of uploaded images should be good.

Please see the attached screen shot. The top blue image are users' original image files which are in different dimensions and aspect ratios. The bottom red image is image file uploaded onto server which has fixed dimensions and aspect ratio.

[image]

Image files can be png, gif, jpg, bmp.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not an expert of different type of images but I do know the not all type can be edited.  The quality of the image and image type is an ascii string at the beginning of the file.  You can open the image with note pad and see the ascii header.   So some images can be scaled and others you cannot scale.  After scaling to maintain aspect ratio you will need to crop.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You will always lose quality when you resize an image unless it is vector graphics. Sadly, mostly they are not vector graphics.

**Upscaling**

If say you have an image which is 5px × 5px, and you want to enlarge it to 10px × 10px, where will the 75 new pixels come from? That's right, it will need to be made up somehow. Different algorithms exist to makeup these new pixels such as nearest neighbor, bilinear, bicubic etc. Some tools even have sharpening capabilities.

**Downscaling**

If you have an image which is 5px × 5px, and you want to reduce it to 2px × 2px, you will lose 21 pixels.

**More Info**

Therefore you will always lose quality but tricks can be used to make it seem, to the naked eye, as if no pixels were lost or added. A simple rule to keep in mind is never to go beyond 300% or you will start noticing quality loss. Also, it is better to start with a larger image so ask the users to upload a larger image so you can then downscale.

I use a c# library called [ImageResizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer) to do resizing. It is available as a NuGet package.

> The ImageResizer v4 core library and 18 plugins in the Essential edition are free and open-source under the Apache 2 license.

See [overview](https://imageresizing.net/pricing/for/micro) in licensing.

If you're interested in the algorithms, see [this](https://petapixel.com/2016/09/08/math-behind-digital-photo-resizing-works/) article.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems the ImageResizer library is not free?

Comment: @thomas.benz It is free. Some of its features are not free. *The ImageResizer v4 core library and 18 plugins in the Essential edition are free and open-source under the Apache 2 license.* See [overview](https://imageresizing.net/pricing/for/micro)

Comment: What are of image file extensions are allowed to be edited? Or which  image file extensions are the best to do resize and crop? Thanks.